# changing label of tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

the code might be a little non-standart / messy. it's basically a guess the number game..

Any way, i want to change the `label` after the user pressing the yes/no button. i had some ideas but non of them worked well.. please help me :)

currently the label is "start from last time?" and i would like to change it to "choose a number between 1 - 99".

```
label = Label(root, text="start from last time?")
label.pack()
```

this is the function that activates when the user pressing the button, you can ignore what is written there just add the code :)

```
def yes():
fd = open("save.txt", "r")
data = fd.read()
data = data.split("|")
global answer
answer = int(data[0])
global attempts
attempts = int(data[1])
fd.close()

btnYes.pack_forget()
btnNo.pack_forget()

entryWindow.pack()
btnCheck.pack()
btnQuit.pack()
btnSave.pack()
root.geometry("500x150")
text.set("You Have {0} attempts Remaining! Good Luck!".format(attempts))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to change the tk.Label text there are two ways to do it.

```
Label.config(text="Whaterver you want")
```

or

```
Label["text"] = "New Text"
```